# Testing ARKit + CoreLocation Integration Outside Supported Regions: Simulators or Alternatives?

Tags: swift, arkit, core-location

I'm eager to embark on a project involving the integration of ARKit and CoreLocation utilizing Apple's ARWorldTrackingConfiguration. However, I've encountered an obstacle as my current location is outside of the supported region for ARGeoTrackingConfiguration—I reside in India. Despite attempting to check availability with ARGeoTrackingConfiguration.checkAvailability, it's unavailable in my location. Are there any alternative methods or tools, such as simulators or other solutions, that would allow me to test this functionality in an unsupported region?"

Answer (score 1):

Please check Apple's doc [Recording and Replaying AR Session Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/recording_and_replaying_ar_session_data) on the steps to record AR session data using Reality Composer app. You'll need someone to record that data (.mov files) for you in available region.

You can test the data using [Tracking Geographic Locations in AR](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arkit_in_ios/content_anchors/tracking_geographic_locations_in_ar) app provided by Apple to test if the data is valid.